# Combine results of 2 SQL queries into 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-administration

I have two sql queries as below

```
1. ;with test as (.........) 
   select  abc from (select ... from test)

2. ;with test1 as (....)
   select  abc from (select ... from test1)
```

Both of the queries have the same columns, but different conditions. I want to combine the results of these into a single datafile.

I tried doing query 1 union query 2, but

I am not able to use union as "Incorrect syntax near ';'" when it encounters the ';' of the second query

Answer (score 3):

You could declare multiple CTEs in a single query:

```
WITH Test AS (
    SELECT ...
),
Test1 AS (
    SELECT ..
)
SELECT <column_list> FROM Test

UNION

SELECT <column_list> FROM Test1;
```

Answer (score 1):

use stacked `CTE`

```
;with test as (.......), 
      test1 as (......)
 select  abc from (select ... from test)
  union all
 select  abc from (select ... from test1)
```

show the original query, may be a better alternative could be suggested

Answer (score 0):

Something like this..? Your SQL is rather unclear as it's been heavily redacted.

```
WITH test AS (.........),
test1 AS (....)
SELECT abc
FROM test
UNION
SELECT abc
FROM test1;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to this problem:

Approach 1:

```
With test as (..........),
     test1 as (.........)
Select * from test
UNION
Select * from test1;
```

Approach 2:

```
Create view test as (.....)
Create view test1 as (.....)
Select * from test
UNION
Select * from test1;
```

Comment: Why `CREATE` views? Are the additional objects really needed?

Comment: I have suggested two approaches using which above task can be completed. I would prefer first approach but if one wants a clear picture of both the query logics in a complex query, views can help to separately understand each query.